# Install ffmpeg-php on CentOS

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm trying to install ffmpeg-php on server (CentOS) but after the "make" command I get an error:

```
  from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
  /usr/include/bits/stat.h:91: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
  /usr/include/bits/stat.h:92: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
  /usr/include/bits/stat.h:93: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
  In file included from /usr/local/include/php/main/php_streams.h:28,
             from /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:400,
             from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
  /usr/include/sys/stat.h:367: error: array type has incomplete element type
  /usr/include/sys/stat.h:374: error: array type has incomplete element type
  In file included from /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:406,
             from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:



/usr/local/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:218: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'time_t'
/usr/local/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:246: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'time_t'
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c: In function 'zm_startup_ffmpeg':
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:94: warning: implicit declaration of function 'avcodec_init'
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

The ffmpeg was installed successfully as well as mplayer and mencoder.

ffpeg:

```
 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-version3
 libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
 libavcodec     54. 56.100 / 54. 56.100
 libavformat    54. 27.101 / 54. 27.101
 libavdevice    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
 libavfilter     3. 16.104 /  3. 16.104
 libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
 libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
 libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

Any help?

Comment: Please help me !!!! ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226157/how-to-setup-ffmpeg-for-centos-release-6-5-server

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like ffmpeg-php won't work with a newer libavcodec, they replaced avcodec_init with another function you could probably recode the one call if its replacement is returning the same thing. It doesn't look like ffmpeg-php has been updated in a long time but you might want to try the HEAD version from svn

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-April/123454.html

Comment: Please help me !!!! ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226157/how-to-setup-ffmpeg-for-centos-release-6-5-server

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way to Install FFmpeg**

This tutorial walks you through installing FFmpeg on CentOS 8, 7, 6

1. Deploy a new CentOS cloud server instance.
2. Login to root ssh download [Bitvise SSH Client](https://tutsfx.com/best-ssh-clients-for-windows-server-root-access-software/)

**Installing FFmpeg on CentOS 8**

```html
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

```html
yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
```

```html
yum install http://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/SDL2-2.0.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```html
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel -y
```

[Installing FFmpeg on CentOS 7](https://tutsfx.com/how-install-ffmpeg-centos-8-vps-dedicated/)