# How to setup ffmpeg for CentOS release 6.5 server

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, centos, screenshot

I need to create a screen shot from video,

I have followed [this](http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/02/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-for-windows-apache-http-server/) tutorial to do the intial setup in window 8, php 5.3

1) I downloaded the ffmpeg from here -[ 
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ ]  for 64 bit operating system.

2) I followed the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU49GiWGGAI  , video and did all configuration successfully and `phpinfo()` shows that `ffmpeg` has been installed.

3) Then I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/r8JDpxnL) to find out whether it is working or not,

It worked successfully

4) Next I followed this video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT4hN5o57hI) and thumbnails were created successfully.

below is my code

```
/**
 * FFMPEG-PHP Test Script
 *
 * Special thanks to http://www.sajithmr.me/ffmpeg-sample-code for this code example!
 * See the tutorial at http://myownhomeserver.com on how to install ffmpeg-php.
 */
error_reporting(1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
// Check if the ffmpeg-php extension is loaded first
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

// Determine the full path for our video
$vid = realpath('./videos/myvideo.mp4');
$videosize = filesize($vid);
$remoteVideo = 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4';

//ffmpeg

$ffmpeg = dirname(__FILE__) . "\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
$imageFile = "1.png";
$image2 = "2.png";
$size = "120x90";
$getfromsecond = 7;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $vid -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $imageFile";
$cmd2 = "$ffmpeg -i $remoteVideo -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $image2";
if(!shell_exec($cmd)){
    echo "Thumbnail created";
}else{
    echo "Error Creating thumbnail";
}

if(!shell_exec($cmd2)){
    echo "Thumbnail for remote url was created";
}else{
    echo "Error Creating thumbnail for remote url ";
}
```

---

```
  OUTPUT
    Thumbnail created
    Thumbnail for remote url was created
```

Now above code works as expected in my local, in window machine , I need to do it in my server environment(Linux server) with php 5.5. How do I do the configuration for ffmpeg in CentOS release 6.5 server with php 5.5.

I have followed this tutorial to install it in server

1.http://supportlobby.com/blog/ffmpeg-installation-on-centos-6-5/

2.http://tecadmin.net/install-ffmpeg-on-linux/

> **OUTPUT IN CONSOLE**

```
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.2.1
built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# which ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# ffmpeg -formats
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (coffee) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
```

### **But in server when I open my php file I am getting this error `Error in loading ffmpeg`**

Also I have checked phpinfo(), It shows ffmpeg installed in my local but not in server.

What else I need to do to configure ffmpeg in Cent Os 6.5  php 5.5.

Comment: Do you have root access on your linux box? What Linux is installed there?

Comment: Maybe its already installed check in console with `which ffmpeg` it will give you full path to ffmpeg, so just replace the path in your `$ffmpeg` variable

Comment: nope it is not installed I have checked

Comment: Sorry guys, I checked with the team it is CentOS release 6.5... I am getting error `Error in loading ffmpeg`

Comment: it seems to be installed but it is throwing error when I am checking the extension `extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');` ....

Comment: I have checked `var_dump(extension_loaded('ffmpeg'))`, it shows `bool(false) `

Answer (score 1):

I could not find your installation steps or commands, You need to configure with ffmpeg-php,

```
#  git clone https://github.com/tony2001/ffmpeg-php.git
#  cd ffmpeg-php
#  make clean
#  phpize 
#  ./configure 
#  make
#  make install

# vim /usr/lib/php.ini 
[ffmpeg]
extension=ffmpeg.so

# pkill -9 httpd
#  /etc/init.d/httpd start

# php -i|grep ffmpeg

ffmpeg
ffmpeg-php version => 0.7.0
```